# Is there a way to select an ALIAS for a certain value in select query in db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I am querying data from the following query

```
select count(*) as Total, slabreached
from mwp_main
where 
    problemsince >= current timestamp - 7 days 
    and problemsince < current timestamp
    and status not in ('OPEN','REASSIGNED','REASSIGNED RESPONSE','REOPEN')
group by slabreached
```

The above query is returning the following result

```
TOTAL  SLABREACHED
 93            0
  7            1
```

`SLABREACHED` only contains `0`s and `1`s.

But I want to replace `0` with `SLABREACHED` and `1` with `WithInSLA` in my select query as I cannot change the dataset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using `CASE WHEN` Expression

```
select count(*) as Total,case when SLABREACHED=0 then 'SLABREACHED' 
when SLABREACHED=1 then 'WithInSLA' end as SLABREACHED
from mwp_main
where problemsince >= current timestamp - 7 days and problemsince < current timestamp
and status not in ('OPEN','REASSIGNED','REASSIGNED RESPONSE','REOPEN') 
group by slabreached
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks this query worked. I would also like to calculate the percentage of SLABREACHED and WithInSLA in same query. I am unable to add it in the current query.
Any clue would be very helpful

Comment: I am able to calculate percentage in a separate query 
select count(*) , ((sum(case when slabreached = 0 then 1 else 0 end)*100.0)/count(*)) as WithInSlaPercent,
((sum (case when slabreached = 1 then 1 else 0 end)*100.0)/count(*)) as ExceedingSlaPercent
from mwp_main
where problemsince >= current timestamp - 7 days and problemsince < current timestamp
and status not in ('OPEN','REASSIGNED','REASSIGNED RESPONSE','REOPEN') 


But unable to do it in the same query. 
@fa06

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you wouldn't want the results in a single row:

```
select sum(SLABREACHED) as WithInSLA,
       sum(1 - SLABREACHED) as SLABREACHED
from mwp_main
where problemsince >= current timestamp - 7 days and
      problemsince < current timestamp and
      status not in ('OPEN', 'REASSIGNED',' REASSIGNED RESPONSE', 'REOPEN') ;
```